# Exportación errónea de informes de JasperReports

Tags: java, excel, jasper-reports

Estoy implementando una exportación de informes `JasperReports` (creados con iReport 3.6.0). Me está dando ciertos problemas que no consigo depurar ni solucionar. En primer lugar, los ficheros que se descargan son detectados como `html` por el navegador, aunque en el caso de los pdf se pueden abrir sin problemas y contienen la información deseada. En segundo lugar, y más molesto, es que los excel exportados, también detectados como `html`, contienen en este caso `html`, el de la página destino para ser más exactos, en lugar del informe que corresponde. Este es mi código:

```
List jasperlist = new ArrayList();
jasperlist = getInvoicesForOneDistributor(distributorsList,periodId,format);

try {           
                        
    byte[] result = null;
    
    if (format.equalsIgnoreCase("pdf"))
    {
        JRPdfExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        exporter.setParameter(JRPdfExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT_LIST, jasperlist);
        exporter.setParameter(JRPdfExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM,byteArrayOutputStream); 
        exporter.exportReport();
        result = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
    }
    else
    {
        JRXlsExporter exporter = new JRXlsExporter();               
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT_LIST, jasperlist);
        exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM,byteArrayOutputStream);
        exporter.setParameter(JExcelApiExporterParameter.IS_REMOVE_EMPTY_SPACE_BETWEEN_ROWS, Boolean.TRUE);
        exporter.setParameter(JExcelApiExporterParameter.IS_WHITE_PAGE_BACKGROUND, Boolean.FALSE);
        exporter.setParameter(JExcelApiExporterParameter.IS_DETECT_CELL_TYPE, Boolean.TRUE);
        //we set the one page per sheet parameter here
        exporter.setParameter(JExcelApiExporterParameter.IS_ONE_PAGE_PER_SHEET, Boolean.TRUE);                
        exporter.exportReport();
        result = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
    }
    
    String contentType="";
    if (format.equalsIgnoreCase("pdf"))
    {
        contentType="application/pdf";
    }
    else
    {
        contentType="application/vnd.ms-excel";
    }

    response.setContentType(contentType);
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"Factures_distribuidors."+format+"\"");
    ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
    out.write(result, 0, result.length);
    out.flush();
    
} catch (JRException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} 

private static List getInvoicesForOneDistributor(String datos, String period, String format)
{
    EntityManager em = new EntityManager();
    Connection connection = em.getConnection();
    List jasperlist = new ArrayList();
    String[] opciones = datos.split(",");
    HashMap parametros = new HashMap();
    parametros.put("contentType", format.toUpperCase());
    parametros.put("period_id", period);
    parametros.put("operator_id", opciones[1]);//campo 1 es el id del distribuidor

    if (opciones[2].equalsIgnoreCase("true")) //por titulo
    {
        JasperPrint jasperPrintTitol = getPrint("LIQ_FACTURA_DISTRIBUIDOR1", parametros,connection);
        if (jasperPrintTitol != null)
        {
            jasperlist.add(jasperPrintTitol);
        }
    }
    
    if (opciones[3].equalsIgnoreCase("true")) //por terminal
    {
        JasperPrint jasperPrintTerminal = getPrint("LIQ_FACTURA_DISTRIBUIDOR2", parametros,connection);
        if (jasperPrintTerminal != null)
        {
            jasperlist.add(jasperPrintTerminal);
        }
    }
    try {
        connection.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return jasperlist;
}

private static JasperPrint getPrint(String reportName, HashMap parameters,Connection connection)
    {
        
        InputStream resourcecompiled = ATMReporter.class.getResourceAsStream(reportFolder + reportName + reportCompiledExtension);
        try {            
            JasperReport jasperReport = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(resourcecompiled);
            JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parameters, connection);             
            return jasperPrint;                        
            
        } catch (JRException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
        
    }
```

He probado diversos cambios y alternativas sin tener ningún resultado positivo. Esta es la última iteración de lo que he implementado. Sé que el código está obsoleto, pero es la versión que usa la aplicación que mantengo y no se puede actualizar. Por supuesto he revisado logs y no veo nada raro. ¿Alguien ve algo que se me escape?. Gracias.

Comment: Revisando no se ve un error, yo te recomendaría que pruebes quitando `attachment;` del `Content-Disposition` porque yo he tenido problemas en internet Explorer de esa forma, valida que la variable `format` realmente tiene un valor o prueba colocar el nombre con le extensión para descartar.

Comment: Gracias por comentar. Quitando `attachment` lo único que pasa es que intenta imprimir en pantalla el contenido del xls, configuración del mismo incluída. He añadido `out.close()` como has sugerido, gracias por recordármelo, lo debí borrar sin darme cuenta. Con format he comprobado ya que contiene el valor correcto de la extensión y he probado hardcodeándola, sin resultados. Lo que me lleva de cabeza es porqué el contenido del excel es una página web en vez del informe de jasper, no logro entenderlo.